# SQLite: Table containing largest score per period by USER

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
USER    PERIOD  SCORE
A       1       8
A       1       9
A       2       2
A       2       3
A       3       4
A       3       5
B       1       2
B       1       3
B       2       5
B       2       4
B       3       4
B       3       4
C       1       2
C       1       3
C       2       3
C       2       5
C       3       3
C       3       4
```

I need to calculate the average score per period per user, so I need to transform a table into this

```
USER    PERIOD  SCORE
A       1       8.5
A       2       2.5
A       3       4.5
B       1       2.5
B       2       4.5
B       3       4
C       1       2.5
C       2       4
C       3       3.5
```

And then finally, I need to create a table with only the highest score in each period and the corresponding user, like this

```
USER    PERIOD  SCORE
A       1       8.5
B       2       4.5
A       3       4.5
```

I can do this by creating two tables, but I'd like to be a fancy queryist and do it all in one step. Any pointers? These are my queries so far:

```
CREATE TABLE STEP1 AS SELECT
    USER
    ,PERIOD
    ,AVG(SCORE) AS SCORE
FROM STEP0
GROUP BY 1,2
;
CREATE TABLE STEP2 AS SELECT
    PERIOD
    ,MAX(SCORE) AS SCORE
FROM STEP1
GROUP BY 1
;
CREATE TABLE FINAL AS SELECT
    A.USER
    ,B.PERIOD
    ,B.SCORE
FROM STEP1 A
    JOIN STEP2 B
        ON A.SCORE=B.SCORE
;
```

I'm using SQLite DB Browser, but if what I'm asking can't be done using it, ie we need a function not available in SQLite DB Browser , I can use another SQL app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL AS 
SELECT tt.* 
FROM (
    SELECT t.user,t.period,AVG(t.score) as score
    FROM STEP0 t
    GROUP BY t.user,t.period ) tt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STEP0 s
                  WHERE s.period = tt.period
                  GROUP BY s.user
                  HAVING AVG(s.score) > tt.score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO STEP1
SELECT users, Period, AVG(CAST(score AS float)) AS score
    FROM TEST a
    GROUP BY users, Period

SELECT * FROM STEP1

INSERT INTO STEP2
SELECT 
A.Period,
Max(A.score) as score 
FROM
STEP1 A 
GROUP BY A.Period

SELECT * FROM STEP2

INSERT INTO FINAL
SELECT A.users, A.Period, A.score 
FROM STEP1 A 
INNER JOIN STEP2 B ON A.score = B.score AND A.Period = B.Period

SELECT * FROM FINAL
```

Comment: There is a possibility to get multiple users for same period in FINAL table if they have scored max together..